# Income effect in perfect substitutes if the already cheaper good becomes more cheaper?

Tags: microeconomics, slutsky-equation, income-effect, perfect-substitutes

Consider a simple utility function U(x,y) = x+y such that P<sub>x</sub> < P<sub>y</sub> (which means only x is being consumed at optimal point, a corner solution).

In this case, assume P<sub>x</sub> falls further. Now won't the consumption of x increase further, and won't that be due to income effect entirely?

In the book i am studying from(Hal Varian), the author assumes P<sub>y</sub> reduces so that consumption shifts entirely from x to y, and concludes that perfect substitutes have no income effect.

But clearly, doesn't it depend on which commodity's price decreases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perfectly right. The analysis in Varian's *Intermediate Microeconomics* is incomplete. If the consumed good doesn't switch, then the entire effect is a pure income effect. This has also been noted [in the literature](https://libjournals.mtsu.edu/index.php/jfee/article/download/1496/1075).